# Is there a way to force Checkstyle to ignore particular warning in the source code?

Tags: java, checkstyle

PMD has a way to ignore particular warning with `//NOPMD`comment inside Java source file.

Does Checkstyle have similar option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, look at the [SuppressionCommentFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Filters) and [SuppressWithNearbyCommentFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Filters) options.