# Checkstyle suggests impossible constant ordering

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have several long String constants (`static final` variables) that share a common fragment. The fragment does not have any meaning on its own, so I declared it as a "private static final".

For example:

```
private static final XML_H = "<?xml ....";
public static final DOC_1 = XML_H + "<tag....";
public static final DOC_2 = XML_H + "<tag....";
```

Now I get an warning from checkstyle

```
Variable access definition in wrong order
```

Which is from the Declaration Order Check rule which is saying private should come after public.

If I move `XML_H` to where it is "supposed" to be, the code does not compile because field cannot be referred to before it is declared.

To me this seems to be a bug in the rule because this is a real language limitation and there's no other way to do this. I think the rule should exclude this case from checking.

Do you guys agree or is there any way to improve the code without the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in that the [DeclarationOrder](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#DeclarationOrder) check does not cover your case.

This is a reasonable restriction of this check, because Checkstyle works on source code exclusively and thus has no compiler information available. So, while your specific case could be handled, similar other cases lead to problems with runtime type resolution and scoping. In other words, I would not really expect them to enhance the Checkstyle tool.

In order to deal with this, you can set the check's `ignoreModifiers` option to `true`, which will tell Checkstyle to ignore your case while still checking that methods and constructors come after the fields. This should be reasonable.

If you cannot change the rule (i.e. by corporate restriction) and the responsible person cannot be persuaded, then you can move the private constant to a `private static` inner class. This will also make the violation go away, but of course it will make your code worse. (Which would be really sad.)

Comment: Wow. I didn't realize the limit on checkstyle's is at this level. Luckily, the centrally configured xml has suppression enabled so I can at least disable it line by line.

Answer (score 3):

It's not so much a bug in the rule, but rather a limitation of the rule. Just suppress the warning with the techniques covered in these questions:

- [How do I Suppress Warnings in CheckStyle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565840/how-do-i-suppress-warnings-in-checkstyle)
- [How to disable a particular checkstyle rule for a particular line of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023185/how-to-disable-a-particular-checkstyle-rule-for-a-particular-line-of-code)

You can't easily change that code. You don't want to do something hacky to just please checkstyle.

Comment: Yeah, I am currently using `// SUPPRESS CHECKSTYLE DeclarationOrder` on every affected constant, but this looks extremely ugly. Do you not think it's reasonable for them to exclude this case? Maybe as an option to the rule?